# Python environment names missing

Tags: anaconda

If I list my python environments I get a number of unnamed or nameless environments:

```
(base)$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/drf/anaconda
                         /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/arc
                         /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/grids
                         /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/junk
                         /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/msr
                         /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/py27
base                  *  /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/py37
                         /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/pygridgen
                         /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/pynomo
                         /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/python3
                         /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/pytides
                         /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/pytides3
                         /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/wxpython

(base)$
```

I can activate them with their path names, but I can't use shortnames to activate them:

```
(base) $ conda activate base
(base) $ conda activate /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/arc
(arc) $ conda activate /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/grids
(grids) $ conda activate /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/junk
(junk) $ conda activate /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/msr
(msr) $ conda activate /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/py27
(py27) $ conda activate /Users/drf/anaconda/envs/py37
(py37) $
```

But I cannot use the shortnames:

```
(msr)$ conda activate msr
Could not find conda environment: msr
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

Where are the short names stored and how do I get their utility back?

Comment: what is the version of conda you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you deactivate the activated environments.  If you create multiple environments and activate them, they act as child processes and won't recognize the changes in the parent.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I upgraded conda and anaconda. You need to add the path to your environments using:

```
conda config --add envs_dirs <path to envs>
```

For example, after I upgraded I got the following:

```
(base) $ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/mah/anaconda
                         /Users/mah/anaconda/envs/ase3
base                  *  /Users/mah/opt/anaconda3
```

Note that my old environments were in /Users/mah/anaconda… whereas my new install is expecting the environments to be in /Users/mah/opt/anaconda3. The solution in this specific case was:

```
(base) $ conda config --add envs_dirs /Users/mah/anaconda/envs
(base) $ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/mah/anaconda
ase3                     /Users/mah/anaconda/envs/ase3
base                  *  /Users/mah/opt/anaconda3
```